# Robotframework + phantomjs error

Tags: python, phantomjs, robotframework

I tried to run test with robotframework + phantomjs. In past it's worked correctly, but suddenly I got this message:
-other infos: Our server got a new python version.

```
Suite setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: Service phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status 
code was: 0
```

For other users, the process executed properly.

Comment: If you dont use PhantomJS and just use a normal driver does it pass normally? (IE, no errors) - What was the Python version before and now?

Comment: Try this command " sudo apt-get install libfontconfig "

Comment: sudo apt-get install libfontconfig is a reliable answer, but my problem was with a config file :) But thanks guys! :)

Comment: @AttilaKis So, the problem is fixed and no longer an issue? if so id recommend that you write an answer for this question so future people see this and can get some help :) glad the issue has been resolved though!